# Not starting printing on bed

Tags: adhesion

I'm a complete newby

Monoprice maker select v.2

Followed directions home all turn off machine level bed
Turn on
Z position fast up an inch
Preheat pla
Print

Then it goes back down but not to the bed above it Pla doesn't stick

Why does it not go back to where I put it when I did the leveling?

Comment: Welcome to 3dPrinting.SE!

Comment: I'm not an expert with the Monoprice, but it seems to me the printer needs to be on when you level the bed. If you don't, the printer won't know it's been moved. Secondarily, if your z-axis end stop isn't set right, it won't know where the end of travel *should* be.